# Multiline unnumbered chapter in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I don't need to have numbers of chapters, sections, etc in my table of contents. But some names a too long so they are multiline.

Their next line appear a bit right then first line. And the width of that empty space is same as if there was number on first line. How to remove that indentation from second and next lines?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, you should not use such long chapter names. That's why `\chapter[....]{...}` is designed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some possibilities:

- Use `\protect\numberline{}` to apply the usual indent for the chapter
- Remove the space of `\cftchapnumwidth` by setting it temporarily to `0pt` (write this to the `ToC`) and restore later on.
- `\hfill very very`

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\newlength{\standardchapnumwidth}

\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\standardchapnumwidth}{\cftchapnumwidth}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{0pt}

% With indentation:

    \chapter*{Very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long title}

\chapter*{Very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\hfill Very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long title}



\addtocontents{toc}{\setlength{\protect\cftchapnumwidth}{0pt}}
\chapter*{Very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long title}


\addtocontents{toc}{\setlength{\protect\cftchapnumwidth}{\standardchapnumwidth}}
\chapter{Very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Best don't use such long titles at all!